# Issues writing text file to IFS though jt400

Tags: java, jruby, ibm-midrange, jt400, ibm-ifs

All I'm trying to do is to drop a log on IFS

Here is my code:

```
  def write(target_filename, data)
    stream = com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFileOutputStream.new(AS400.sys, target_filename)
    stream.write(data.to_java_bytes)
    stream.flush
    stream.close
  end
```

When i read it though the jt400 library, it comes out ok.

But when i go thought the `qShell` or `wrklnk` the file seems empty.

Any ideas why? Is it the CCID?

Comment: `... the file seems empty.` Meaning what? You view attributes for the size? Or you run utilities to display content? Or...? What do you run? What happens?

Comment: IFSFileOutputStream stream = new IFSFileOutputStream(as400, "/Dir/File");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using `IFSFileOutputStream` to write binary stream of text. By switching it to `IFSTextFileOutputStream`, problem was resolved.